# determine file extension of a saved image (or any file)

Tags: php, file-type

What is the most efficient way to determine the extension of a saved file, given that I know the name only and not the extension?

Valid types/extensions are .jpg, .png and .gif

For example, every item has an image, so the image name will be 

  `item1.jpg or item1.png or item1.gif
  item2.jpg or item2.png or item2.gif
etc.`

The only way I can think of so far is looping through the three possibilities with

```
if(file_exists('item1.jpg')) {...
} elseif(file_exists('item1.png')) {...
} elseif(file_exists('item1.gif')) {...
}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: yes, the items are db-driven articles so /page/item23/ will have an associated image img src="/images/item23.jpg". I know the "/images/item23" part but it could be any one of the three file types. I could store the image name along wth the article content but I am thinking this may be unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For efficient in terms of less code, you could do

```
$name = 'item23';
$images = glob("images/$name.???");
$image = $images ? $images[0] : '';
```

which should return the first file matching your filename, regardless of which extension it has, or `''` if no matching file is found. I *think* that should also be more efficient in terms of execution time than checking `file_exists` three times.

---

In my unsolicited opinion, I think storing the full paths to images associated with your articles isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, this is along the lines of what I was looking for. I don't know if it the most efficient method but it works :) In terms of storing the full filename, most of the time the type will be .jpg so I want something to handle the exceptions rather than all instances. Your method seems to be the best solution. (Am also considering storing the ext as a tiny int, e.g.  0=>'jpg',1=>'png',2=>'gif'). Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

This should check the MIME of the file and give you the type

Comment: thanks, but to do that I would first need to know the file name+extension :)